# How to see the files that were written to disk from node.js app hosted on heroku?

Tags: node.js, heroku

I have a node.js app on heroku and I sometimes need to write files to heroku. Do you know how to see those files? Should I delete them after I am finished using them? I do not want to use memory for no reason.

Answer (score 1):

Heroku (and other container based platforms) are different from traditional servers that you might be used to. It's worth bearing in mind that the Heroku filesystem is [ephemeral](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/dynos#ephemeral-filesystem) - that means that any changes to the filesystem whilst the dyno is running only last until that dyno is shut down or restarted. Each dyno boots with a clean copy of the filesystem from the most recent deploy.

If you really needed to check a file on a running dyno (let's say to debug an issue with a file upload) it is possible to login using Heroku Exec https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/exec

That said, you really shouldn't be using the filesystem for anything other than temporary files. Instead you should aim to use external services for persistent storage as described here: https://12factor.net/

For example, if you are handling file uploads you could try storing these on a service like Amazon S3.