# Python os.remove() not working on herouku

Tags: python, csv, flask, heroku

I deployed two .py files and 4 excel files on heroku. 
1st .py file is for front end (Flask) which takes data from csv files and the second one for extracting the data from api and building the model which alters the excel file data. The need is to run the second script daily

path for app.py(Flask)
/app/app.py-- along with the excel files.

path for script file 
/app/Scripts/intra_day.py

Proc file content
web: gunicorn app:app
worker: python Scripts/intra_day.py

The problem is the script runs successfully but the excel files are not altered. There was no issue when the script ran in local. Please find the below python script

```
dir=os.getcwd()
print(dir)



os.chmod("Nifty_100.csv", stat.S_IRWXU)
os.chmod("Nifty_50.csv", stat.S_IRWXU)
os.chmod("forecast_nifty50.csv",stat.S_IRWXU)
os.chmod("forecast_nifty100.csv", stat.S_IRWXU)


# %%
os.remove("Nifty_100.csv")
os.remove("forecast_nifty100.csv")
```

The whole scripts run successfully but it is not removing and altering the files. Tried placing them in separate folders. Still, it is not removing.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to see the files that were written to disk from node.js app hosted on heroku?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51775662/how-to-see-the-files-that-were-written-to-disk-from-node-js-app-hosted-on-heroku)

Comment: (The duplicate I picked is for Node.js, not Python, but the situation is exactly the same.)